# How to pass state to component ? React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to pass a state with value - 3 to another functional component that uses value - 1. How can I do that ?

My code:

Screen 1.

```
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function ScreenOne() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(1);

  return (
      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
              navigation.navigate("ScreenTwo", setMyState(myState(3)))
          }
      >
          <Text>Go to another screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );  }
```

Screen 2.

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function screenTwo() {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(1);

  const route = useRoute();

  const setMyState = route.params;

  return (
      <View>
          <Text>myState</Text>
      </View>
  ); }
```

For example, the myState in the first screen has the value 1, after clicking the button in the first screen I need to change the value of myState the state 3 in the second screen.

Comment: Did you tried to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the common parent of your two function components ?

Comment: No, this is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

To share state between two sibling function components you need to lift the state up to their common parent component. The state must be located only in the parent.

First screen: you just need to handle the new state and lift up to the parent component.

```js
export default function ScreenOne({ handleState }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
      <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
              handleState(3)
              navigation.navigate("ScreenTwo")
          }}
      >
          <Text>Go to another screen</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Second screen: you only need to get state value.

```js
export default function ScreenTwo({ state }) {
  return (
      <View>
          <Text>{state}</Text>
      </View>
  );
}
```

Parent component: you have your useState here, so childs components can interact with it like this.

```js
function Parent() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  return {
    <View>
      <ScreenOne handleState={(state) => setState(state)} />
      <ScreenTwo state={state} />
    </View>
  }
}
```